# Mysqli UPDATE query for date type fails by code, successful by command line

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

This query returns 0 affected rows.

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE dates SET date = '$date' WHERE url = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $url) ."'")
```

If I print the sql query out, it looks like this --

```
UPDATE dates SET date = '2012-10-25' WHERE url = 'http://foo.com'
```

If I manually do this on the command line, it works just fine.

Why would my mysqli_query() be failing?

**EDIT:**

If I show warnings I get --

```
Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date' at row 1
```

My dates seem to be formatted correctly. Why would they be truncated and how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you echoed out your SQL? Does it look like you expect?

Comment: Hope you're escaping `$date` too, or it's code-generated so you know it's safe.

Comment: @andrewsi, yes, the above query is a result of an echo

Comment: @Rudu, yep, code generated, Thx!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  printf("Affected rows : %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($conn));
```

Comment: @allanb what are getting in `printf("%s\n", mysqli_info($conn));` ?

Comment: `Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 1`

Comment: I get `Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date' at row 1` as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to pass that connection resource to mysqli_query and mysqli_real escape_string, just pass it in your select mysqli_select_db like mysqli_select_db('database',$conn)

Comment: string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to check the value on each variables passed on that query: `$date`, `$conn` or `$url` and make sure each of them return any value. But based on your error line, I think it will be your `$date`, there is might be no value returned to that variable or the format of the date is wrong. That's why the query return that error.

Try echoing the value of `$date`.

Comment: My printed query comes from an `echo`. There is definitely a value. If I take that query and run it on a command line it works fine. I used `SHOW WARNINGS` and it returned `Warning (1265): Data truncated for column 'date' at row 1`.

Comment: @allanb: Ah ic, sorry. Try to `select` any data from that query. If it doesn't return any value then it could be your connection.